# Protractor / Chrome - UnknownError: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to run a Protractor test but am receiving the following command line error when trying to test in Chrome.

```
UnknownError: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
```

The test successfully runs in Firefox, i.e. when the protractor.conf.js file is set as such:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
}
```

I'm currently using ChromeDriver 2.10, which seems to have something to do with the issue (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1424). However, I'm unclear how to configure Protractor to use a different version of ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

So, reverting to ChromeDriver 2.9 was as easy as downloading it from here (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/) and extracting the zip into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium`.

That fixed the immediate issue of not being able to run the test in Chrome. Still waiting on a fix for 2.10, I suppose.